# Django best way drawing line chart

Tags: html, django, charts, linechart

I have two models: User and Data. Each user has multiple data, and one data belongs to a User.

So I have the following code:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    z = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'User : ' + self.user.id + ' | Time : '+ str(self.timestamp)
```

On my web application, I have a landing page that shows up all users. Once clicked a user, it shows another empty page. I would like to draw a line chart showing the user x,y,z accelerations over the time on that page.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [django-nvd3](http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes-doc/line-chart.html) like this as they have stated in the documentation...

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import random
import datetime
import time

def demo_linechart(request):
    """
    lineChart page
    """
    start_time = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 1).timetuple()) * 1000)
    nb_element = 100
    xdata = range(nb_element)
    xdata = map(lambda x: start_time + x * 1000000000, xdata)
    ydata = [i + random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(nb_element)]
    ydata2 = map(lambda x: x * 2, ydata)

    tooltip_date = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p"
    extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " cal"},
                   "date_format": tooltip_date}
    chartdata = {'x': xdata,
                 'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_serie,
                 'name2': 'series 2', 'y2': ydata2, 'extra2': extra_serie}
    charttype = "lineChart"
    data = {
        'charttype': charttype,
        'chartdata': chartdata
    }
    return render_to_response('linechart.html', data)
```

Template example:

```
{% load static %}
<link media="all" href="{% static 'nvd3/src/nv.d3.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'd3/d3.min.js' %}'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'nvd3/nv.d3.min.js' %}'></script>

{% load nvd3_tags %}
<head>
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" True "%d %b %Y %H" %}
</head>
<body>
    {% include_container "linechart_container" 400 600 %}
</body>
```

But I think the best way to use [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create api in the backend and

then consume the data of api by any frontend framework like [angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts)

and there are several third party open source projects available in frontend frameworks which can help you achieve any kind of chart

Comment: This seems a good answer. I need to insert more things on the page apart from the line chart. How I can embed this on a div (for example)?

Comment: I have updated the answer ...have a look at documentation ...you will find more..

Comment: I've look at the documentation. It imports 2 javascript and 1 css, but I don't know where are these files, since I've installed django nvd3 via pip.

Comment: Also I've got this error: 'nvd3_tags' is not a registered tag library.

Answer (score 2):

You can user Chart.js or Google charts on your HTML template, and you need to generate Json, for charts on your Django views.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

data = Data.objects.filter(user=user)
json_data = serialize('json', data, cls=LazyEncoder)
```